# Android API call while app is Terminated

Tags: android, android-networking

I have a problem making an API call when the app is completely terminated (app is removed from recent apps list).

Let's say user gets a notification that has a button (`Action`).

When user presses that button, I want to make an API call to update some data on the server.

If the app is in background (not visible to the user but it is in recent apps), it works perfectly. I make the API call and I get a response.

If the app is terminated (not seen in recent apps), it fails. I get the following response for every call:

```
{
  "errors": [
    "not found"
  ]
}
```

So this seems like [HTTP 404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) (`not found`) response.

I am positive that my server is not returning this. If I try the same API call when the app is running or in background, it works.

It seems like Android OS is blocking the network connection because the app is not running.

How would I work around this?

Thank you.

Comment: "It seems like Android OS is blocking the network connection" -- no, because then you would not get *any* response. An HTTP 404 is a response from a server (just not the one that you want). "How would I work around this?" -- since you do not have a [mcve], I am not certain how anyone is going to be able to help you.

Comment: @CommonsWare that was my first guess as well. But how to explain the background vs. terminated cases? I am using `OkHttp` library to make API calls and I compared the background API call vs. terminated app API calls and they are identical. So why would it work every time when the app is in background and not work when app is terminated?